# Getting Phone Number from PN532 NFC

Tags: nfc, rfid, lib-nfc, pn532

I am using a raspberry pi hooked up to an PN532 NFC to print out the following information from an Android phone.

[image]

I was wondering if there is any way to also obtain the phone's number using NFC?
I am getting the impression that NFC does not allow this type of information to be present without third party tool, but I wanted to be certain whether or not this is impossible just using a PN532?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Most mobile are primary designed as a NFC reader/writer for an end user OR as an emulated payment card in a secure section of the OS.

iOS has limited NFC support compared to Android.

For device to device communication you either need NFC Peer to Peer which iOS does not support and Android is dropping support for.

OR

You need one device to emulate a NFC card and one to be a reader/writer and iOS does not support Card emulation for anything but the OS payment App, where as Android does support card emulation.

This leaves the only common ground as the PN532 emulating a card which it can do and the mobile phone writing it's phone number to an emulated card.

The next hurdle iOS and Android don't natively broadcaster the sensitive info of their mobile number out via NFC, therefore you would have to write an App for that IF you app had permission and was able to read the phone number from the device (I'm note sure that is possible and is the subject of another question) but failing that you could just ask the user to enter in their phone number.

So overall, it might be possible to write various apps and the right software for the Raspberry Pi but a lot of work and require users to launch apps to transfer a mobile number.

Comment: So there does not appear to be a way to acquire phone numbers from Android phones without creating an app. At least no easy way with just the PN532 and just the Raspberry Pi.